# Why does the latest version of the forge viewer break my onClick listener?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

### Summary

The most recent version of the forge viewer (6.6.0) throws an "unexpected token" error in my console and some of my $(button).on('click') event will not longer bind in my custom panels (the requested model does load despite the errors)

### What I've tried

I backed the viewer off to version 6.5.0 and my code works, I also removed all code except the initialization logic and I still get the console errors. 
I also have tried every method of binding the event I can think of and none work in the latest viewer version (`$(document).on('click', 'myButton', this.onMyButtonClick)`, `$('#myButton).click(this.onMyButtonClick)`, `$('myButton').bind('click', this.onMyButtonClick)`, `$('myButton').on('click', this.onMyButtonClick)`)

### Code

#### Viewer links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

#### Initialization logic

```
const options = {
    env: `AutodeskProduction`,
    getAccessToken: getForgeToken
  };
  const documentId = `urn:${urn[`urn_string`]}`;

  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
  });

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
      $(`.navbar-div`).css(`margin-bottom`,`10px`);
      const viewable = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), {
        'type': `geometry`,
        'role': `2d`
      }, true);
      if (viewable.length === 0) {
        return;
      }

      const initialViewable = viewable[0];
      const svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(initialViewable);
      const modelOptions = {
        sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath()
      };

      const viewerDiv = document.getElementById(`viewer`);
      viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);

      viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
  }
```

#### Broken click event

```
class MyExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer) {
      super();
      Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer);
    }
    createPanel() {
      const Panel = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel(NOP_VIEWER.container, `myPanel`, `Title`);
      $(Panel.container).append(*some html*);
      Panel.setVisible(true);
      $(`#myPanel`).find(`.docking-panel-close`).remove();
      $(`#myPanel`).find(`.docking-panel-title`).append(myButton);
      $(`#myButton`).click(this.onMyButtonClick.bind(this));
    }
    onMyButtonClick() {
        alert('here');
    }
  }

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(`myExtension`, MyExtension);
```

### Errors and screenshots

#### Error message in console

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at Object.E [as doOperation] (84a694cc-2244-4f8f-90ea-4d32694ed224:13)
    at t.value (84a694cc-2244-4f8f-90ea-4d32694ed224:13)
    at 84a694cc-2244-4f8f-90ea-4d32694ed224:13
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) {msg: "Error while importing 'userFunction'."}
```

[image: Chrome Console Error Messages]

#### Panel header with button

[image: Panel Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: 
Tested and worked on major browsers with the button in the title panel now - live sample [here](https://jsbin.com/togapef/edit?html). Will let Engineering know that this is breaking change but I doubt they'd discourage putting controls there

```
    class MyExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer) {
      super(viewer);
      this.createPanel()

    }
    createPanel() {
      const Panel = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel(NOP_VIEWER.container, `myPanel`, `Title`);
      Panel.setVisible(true);
      $(`#myPanel`).height('100').offset({ top: 10, left: 30 }).find(`.docking-panel-close`).remove();
      $(`#myPanel`).append($('<button/>').text('Test').mousedown(this.onMyButtonClick.bind(this)))
    }
    onMyButtonClick(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('here')
    }
  }
```

Comment: [here](https://codepen.io/reediculous456/pen/gJWOLZ) is a live sample of my issue. Also, my apologies I should have mentioned that I am working with the 2D viewer, not the 3D viewer. This example has the errors i mentioned in the chrome console and the broken click event, but if you change the head to load `6.5` instead of `6.*` all works. You will need to add a urn and token on line 76 and 70.

Comment: Also, your example places the button in the body of the panel. I moved it to the title bar of the panel and the click event stopped working in version 6.6. See that [here](https://codepen.io/reediculous456/pen/Mdmaby)

Comment: see edit - doubt 2/3d had anything to do with it though, definitely had to do with the title bar capturing the mouse down event before it got a chance to trickle down to the button. However this behavior is not replicable with Firefox.

Comment: Thank you for your help, please let me know when this has been resolved. Do you know why I am getting the errors in the chrome console? They don't appear to be affecting anything

Comment: This issue seems to exist in the current version v7.87.0. Click events work in Firefox but not in Chrome.